# Automated naming of .prn or .txt printed files

Tags: printing, driver

Generic/Text Only is a virtual printer included in all windows versions, but we need to give it a name each time, Ut save

In fact, what I need es to have a virtual plain text printer what name automatically the file, with customizable rules, and then send by ftp/sftp the file.

I searched a lot in google, but i can't find and "easy to use" code or solution. I think is not too difficult, but i can't get the goal.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the print samples in the DDK/WDK. These will give you places to start and may even have something that is very close to what you want to do.

Comment: The WDK is the Windows Driver Kit. It contains everything you need to create a Windows driver, including printer drivers. It includes samples of many different types of drivers. The Driver Development Kit (DDK) is the older incarnation of the WDK.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will see the code of pdf creator, I think it will be useful.